# Unexpected nesting of p and ul tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I currently run into a problem handling this xml

```
<detaileddescription>
    <para>

        ParamText1
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
                <para>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</para>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                <para>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</para>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        ParamText2  
    </para>
</detaileddescription>
```

I use the following xslt file.

```
<!-- match each para tag and calls the child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p class="para">      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </p>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="itemizedlist">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="listitem/para">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
```

I'd expect to receive the following result

```
<p class="param">
    ParamText1
    <ul>
        <li>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</li>
        <li>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</li>
    </ul>
    ParamText2
</p>
```

but xslt converts the content in

```
<p class="param">
    ParamText1
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</li>
    <li>Test TextTest TextTest TextTest Text</li>
</ul>
ParamText2
```

I don't know why the `<p>` tag is closed before the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the XSLT processor doing that restructuring and not the HTML parser of some browser? In HTML (both 4 and 5 I think) a `ul` element is not allowed inside of a `p` element so the browsers' parsers usually correct such structures and move the `ul` outside of the `p`.

Comment: Please add your complete XSLT. With only the templates you have included, it is not clear how any built in templates come into play.